# OrientDb get edge by multiple keys

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases

Is there a way to get orientDB edges or vertices by multiple properties?

I only found that I can get them like this:

```
graph.getEdges("age", 20);
```

or:

```
graph.getEdgesOfClass("EdgeClass")
```

But Is it also possible to get them by multiple something like:

graph.getEdgesOfClass("EdgeClass").byProperty(PropertiesMap);

or

```
graph.getEdges("EdgeClass", PropertyMap)
```

I have multiple properties and custom classes and I want to get specific nodes matching this.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the vertices of a specific class with specific properties you can use `g.getVertices("MyClass",new String[] {"key1","key2"}, new Object[] {"value1","value2"});` but for the edges there isn't a similar method.

Could you open a request on github ?

Comment: Thanks, is there at least a way to get edges by start and end node?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know.